# Supabase rpc call wont work with full range of arguments

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, rpc, supabase, supabase-database

I'm writing a React app and using a Supabase rpc to insert rows into a DB table. I'm trying to pass a total of 8 arguments to the postgres function.

The React function for calling the rpc is below:

```
 const confirmTeam = async (user, match, isHomeTeam) => {
    try {

      console.log("matchday", match);
      const { data, error: Error } = await supabase.rpc(
        "confirm_team_selection",
        {
          email: user.email,
          team: isHomeTeam ? match.homeTeamName : match.awayTeamName,
          game_week: match.gameWeek,
          match_id: match.matchId,
          userid: user.id,
          team_id: isHomeTeam ? match.homeTeamId : match.awayTeamId,
          team_location: isHomeTeam ? "HOME_TEAM" : "AWAY_TEAM",
          edition_id: activeEdition,
        }
      );

      if (Error) {
        console.error("Error updating existing active row:", Error);
        return;
      }

      console.log("Data", data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error executing rpc", error);
    }

  };
```

And this is the function being called to insert the values into the DB table:

```
create
or replace function confirm_team_selection (email text, team text, game_week bigint, match_id bigint, user_id uuid, team_id bigint, team_location text, edition_id bigint) returns table (result text) as $$

  -- start transaction
  BEGIN  

  --update existing active rows to inactive
  UPDATE mapping
  SET choice_status = 'inactive'
  WHERE user_id = userid
  AND choice_status = 'active';

  --insert the new row with active choice_status
  INSERT INTO mapping( email, team, game_week, match_id, user_id, team_id, team_location, edition_id, choice_status)
  VALUES(email, team, game_week, match_id, user_id, team_id, team_location, edition_id, 'active');

END;

$$ language plpgsql;
```

but when i call it i get a variation of the following error:

```
code: "PGRST202"
details: "Searched for the function public.confirm_team_selection with parameters edition_id, email, team_location, user_id or with a single unnamed json/jsonb parameter, but no matches were found in the schema cache."
hint: "Perhaps you meant to call the function public.confirm_team_selection(edition_id, match_id, team, userid)"
message: "Could not find the function public.confirm_team_selection(edition_id, email, team_location, user_id) in the schema cache"
```

However i feel this error message is misleading as when i recreate the function to accept and insert the minimal number of arguments (2) everything goes through. I then update the function, increasing the number of arguments it takes, one by one, until it start throwing these errors once it includes 4 to 6 arguments.
What's confusing is that all of the values and arguments definitely work as i have tried adding them in different combinations and they have all worked at some point.

As mentioned i have re-written the postgres script repeatedly with different numbers and combinations of the arguments shown, for example, i started by just including email and user_id and when this worked i amended it to include team, this worked so i then added in game_week and so on until at some point its starts throwing that error. I've then gone back and started again but started with different combinations of arguments to make sure they themselves were not the problem but they've all successfully been inserted at some point. The closest i have got is having 6 of the 8 arguments accepted.

I've tried swapping out some of the values for hardcoded test values but that makes no difference, and the stage at which it starts erroring (as i step by step amend the function to add in arguments) changes each time, i can't find any pattern.

Apologies if this isn't very clear but happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: Looking at your error message, it seems like you are only passing four arguments, `edition_id`, `email`, `team_location`, `user_id`, but could you try again passing all 8 parameters on your client-side call and paste the error message that you get then?

Comment: This is the error message after submitting with all 8 arguments:

code: "PGRST202"
details: "Searched for the function public.confirm_team_selection with parameters edition_id, email, team_location, user_id or with a single unnamed json/jsonb parameter, but no matches were found in the schema cache."
hint: "Perhaps you meant to call the function public.confirm_team_selection(edition_id, email, game_week, match_id, team, team_id, team_location, user_id)"
message:"Could not find the function public.confirm_team_selection(edition_id, email, team_location, user_id) in the schema cache

Comment: Okay, so the error message suggests that you are only passing 4 arguments, `edition_id`, `email`, `team_location`, `user_id` to the function. Make sure on your client side that `team_id`, `match_id`, `game_week`, `team` are being passed and they have values.

Comment: It turns out it was a simple naming mistake on my behalf. I hadn't updated the argument names on the client side correctly.